# How to move up/down div on one place use onclick in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is my first post so I asked for help and possible comments.
I would like to do change div (which is added by using the tool: AddR) by one position up and down when I click "onclick" with jQuery function.
I wrote something like that but it did not work ..
Could someone help me what should I improve?
Thanks for your help

```
<script>
  function AddR(k) {
    Radio_L = Radio_L + 1;
    Radio_N = "Radio" + Radio_L;
    $("#" + k.id + "").append("<div  id='"+Radio_N+"'>" + Radio_N + "<br /><br />" +
      "<button type='submit' class='button' style='float: left;' onclick='AddR(" + Radio_N + ");' >Add</button>" +
      "<button type='submit' class='button' style='float: left;' onclick='UpR(" + Radio_N + ");' >Up</button>" +
      "<button type='submit' class='button' style='float: left;' onclick='DownR(" + Radio_N + ");' >Down</button><br />" +
      "<br />"  + "<input type='text'>" + "<br /><br />" + '</div>'
    );
  }

  function UpR(k) {
    var pos = (this).index();
    var parent = $("#" + k.id + "");
    parent.insertAfter(pos.next());
  }

  function DownR(k) {
    var pos = (this).index();
    var parent = $("#" + k.id + "");
    parent.insertBefore((pos.next());
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would offer a solution which simplifies the HTML, does not put in hard coded HTML in the code and uses classes rather than a lot of code embedded in the markup.

With this markup to start:

```
<div id='Radio_N0' class='container'><span class='containerName'>Radio_N 0</span> 
    <br/>
    <button type='submit' class='button add'>Add</button>
    <button type='submit' class='button up'>Up</button>
    <button type='submit' class='button down'>Down</button>
    <br/>
    <input type='text' />
    <br />
</div>
```

You could use this code to create more of these and move them around:

```
 function AddR(k) {
     Radio_L = $('.container').length;
     var Radio_N = "Radio_N" + Radio_L;
     var newDiv = k.parents('.container').clone();
     newDiv.attr('id', Radio_N).find('.containerName').text(Radio_N);
     newDiv.insertAfter(k.parents('.container'));
 }

 function UpR(k) {
     var parent = k.parents('.container');
     var pos = parent.prev();
     parent.insertBefore(pos);
 }

 function DownR(k) {
     var parent = k.parents('.container');
     var pos = parent.next();
     parent.insertAfter(pos);
 }
 $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
     AddR($(this));
 });
 $(document).on('click', '.up', function () {
     UpR($(this));
 });
 $(document).on('click', '.down', function () {
     DownR($(this));
 });
```

See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/uka2C/

Answer (score 0):

```
var pos = (this).index();
          ^---- Missing $ sign
```

supposed to be

```
var pos = $(this).index();
```

Also

`pos with give you an number` and they **do not have** the `next` method. Only `jQuery objects` do

Try this

```
 function UpR(k) {
        var $elem = $(this).next();
        var parent = $("#" + k.id + "");
        parent.insertAfter($elem);

    }
```

Comment: pos doesn't have method `.next()` also

Comment: I added `<script> var pos = $(this).index(); </script>` but it still does not work

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (also here: http://cdpn.io/AjHyE), i've found some syntax errors:

```
<script>
var Kon_L = 0;

function Kon() {
    Kon_L = Kon_L+ 1;
    var Kon_R_N = "Kon" + Kon_L;

    $("<div id='" + Kon_R_N + "' class='ka' > " + "Kon " + Kon_L + 
      "<button  type='submit' class='button' style='float: left;' onclick='UpR(\"" + Kon_R_N + "\");' >UpDIV</button>" +
      "<button type='submit'  class='button' style='float: left;' onclick='DownR(\"" + Kon_R_N + "\");' >DownDIV</button>" +
      "<br />Tekst<br />" +
      "</div>").appendTo(".Place");
}

function UpR(k) {
    var self = $("#"+k);
    var prev = self.prev();
    self.insertBefore(prev);
}

function DownR(k) {
    var self = $("#"+k);
    var next = self.next();
    self.insertAfter(next);
}
</script>
```

Also check your browser console to see if it's working.

Anyway, since you are asking for comments i'd recommend something to you:

1. remove the HTML from your JS code. You could reference the buttons with some jQuery selector and move them around
2. remove the inline style from HTML, you can easily move the float property inside the button class
3. decouple the JS from the HTML even more, don't use the onclick in the HTML but use the jQuery click() function with the selectors

If you try these modifications i think that you could get more feedback from the Stack Overflow community.

Comment: I did something like that, but unfortunately it does not work ..
Can you help? http://jsfiddle.net/uka2C/1/

Comment: take a look at the code, i've edited it and now it's working, you have the example on codepen